# We are a harmonious family

Tags: riddle

I am the father of seven children.

My first son is a man of action.
My second son's reputation is concerning.
My third son shuttles between London and Leeds in his job.
There is nothing at all I can say about my fourth son.
Surya, my fifth son, is a bright chap.
My sixth son works in Hollywood.
My seventh son is known for his great strength.

--

*Who am I?*

Comment: Nice one!  I had been kicking around a similar idea but yours is much better!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am the father of seven children.

> You are the major scale, and your seven children are the individual tones of the scale expressed in solfege.  A "harmonious family" indeed!

My first son is a man of action.

> DO -- the verb "do"

My second son's reputation is concerning.

> RE -- in correspondence, the abbreviation "Re:" for "regarding", a synonym of "concerning"

My third son shuttles between London and Leeds in his job.

> MI -- the M1 motorway connecting London and Leeds

There is nothing at all I can say about my fourth son.

> FA -- "Sweet F.A." (Fanny Adams), a slang expression meaning "nothing".

Surya, my fifth son, is a bright chap.

> SOL -- i.e. the sun; Surya is the Hindu solar deity

My sixth son works in Hollywood.

> LA -- abbreviation for Los Angeles

My seventh son is known for his great strength.

> TI -- abbreviation for Titanium, the strongest metal

Comment: nice find! i was way off. i'm glad you put me out of my misery

Comment: Good. I intended a different thing for the fourth son, but perhaps it is obscure.

Comment: I've modified my answer with a different slant on the fourth son.  Is this it?

Comment: Actually, your original answer was closer :) [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanny_Adams#References) was what I intended.

Comment: Updated.  Wow I've never heard of that!

Comment: The last one is "Si", for silicon :) | Edit: whoops, no, in english it's not. Well I learn something today !